# Where to start, which books

Tags: beginner, books

What is a good book or resource to start learning Artificial Intelligence ?

Comment: Not sure if a similar question exists already, but this would be a good question for a community wiki answer.

Comment: This question is clearly more suited for a community wiki answer, since **it doesn't have a unique answer**.  The format of Q&A sites is more suited to questions with a "best" answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too broad.  Just asking for references in AI is okay. But, asking for which field to start, is completely opinion based and would have millions of answers for that.

Answer (score 4):

The standard textbooks that covers AI is "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach" by Russel & Norvig. The book's website can be found [here](http://aima.cs.berkeley.edu/).

I also recommend "Artificial Intelligence: Foundations of Computational Agents" by Poole and Mackworth. The book can be read [online](http://artint.info/).

Comment: Russel is the starting point usually

Answer (score 4):

A somewhat popular introduction is Andrew Ng's Stanford  [machine learning lectures](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLA89DCFA6ADACE599)

Comment: A good companion to his web series is [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/ISLR%20First%20Printing.pdf). It has a "physical" book also in addition to the free online PDF.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this free class [Intro to Artificial Intelligence](https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-artificial-intelligence--cs271) from Udacity. One of the instructors is Norvig. The class is more suitable for beginners than Norvig's book.

Even though this class doesn't have programming exercise, it explains concepts so well.

Its follow up class [Artificial Intelligence for Robotics](https://www.udacity.com/course/artificial-intelligence-for-robotics--cs373) has programming exercises and does a fantastic job in explaining Partical Filters.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, but the first link seems not working to me.

Comment: In case the link for Intro to Artificial Intelligence doesn't work, try this: go to udacity.com, click "catalog" on the upper right corner, then type "artificial intelligence" in upper right search box. A list of classes will show up. I just tried this. The second class is "Intro to Artificial Intelligence".

Answer (score 2):

You could start by learning R or Python and Machine Learning in one of those languages.

Some other free options for books are *The LION Way: Machine Learning plus Intelligent Optimization* and *Learning Deep Architectures for AI*, which are both freely available online.

There's also the free and open [Artificial Intelligence course by Berkeley](https://www.edx.org/course/artificial-intelligence-uc-berkeleyx-cs188-1x) at edX.

I have listed all the free books I could find on [machine learning and artificial intelligence books](http://www.learndatasci.com/free-books/) at LearnDataSci, if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you so much, that are good resources, they helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking specifically for books, the leaders in the industry have a variety of recommendations as posted on reddit AMA's of machine learning. One specific book I recommend, which is in preparation at the time, is Deep Learning by Yoshua Bengio et al

There are plenty of resources outside books to learn from as posted [here](http://zhengrui.github.io/zerryland/ML-CV-Resource.html) and [here](http://digitalmind.io/post/deep-learning)

Depends on how much time you have. If you are in it for the long haul, start by brushing up your knowledge on math, specifically Linear Algebra, Calculus, Probability and Statistics

Comment: Thanks for the links. That looks great. I have plenty of time at the moment and I'll work on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have some data science programming experience in R try https://www.datacamp.com/ Is' an interactive online coding environment for learning R programming.